# Load content of page based on URL in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have website which loads content of user based on URL. 
Something like `www.xyz.com/JohnDoe` should load all content of JohnDoe profile.
Similarly if I type some other profile URL it should load content of that particular user.

What is the preferred way to achieve this? I have idea that I need to add `.htaccess` file and get value for URL to show content?

Comment: look for htacces RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Comment: You have to use `.htaccess` to point all requests to PHP file (for example, redirect `www.xyz.com/JohnDoe` to `www.xyz.com/profile.php?userid=JohnDoe`). As Murat Cem YALIN wrote, use `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /user.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now I can go to user profile by  typing

```
example.com/foo
```

Comment: it should be `REQUEST_FILENAME` i guess

Comment: @adelowo That was a typo, I have edited the ans, thanks!